# Querying for SQL Servers in an Inno-setup project

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup

I'm creating a setup using Inno-setup. 
During the setup process, a SQL Server database has to be created.  I want to give the user the ability to select an existing SQL Server instance (if one exists), where the database has to be created.
So, what I want to do in the setup, is to query the network (and the local machine) for SQL Server instances.
Furthermore, when the user has selected an instance, I want to verify if there exists a database on that instance which has a specific name.

Anybody who knows how I can do this ?  Or maybe someone could give me some pointers in the good direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup supports the call of external DLL functions, so you should write a suitable helper DLL. Managed .net DLLs can only be used via a COM interface, otherwise you need an unmanaged DLL.

> Valid calling conventions are: 'stdcall' (the default), 'cdecl', 'pascal' and 'register'.

Comment: +1, except DLL libraries you can even [`use COM objects`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptautomation) in recent versions of InnoSetup (don't know how was before).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following native .Net library call:

```
using System.Data.Sql;

var instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
DataTable dataTable = instance.GetDataSources();
```

The resultant datatable contains the following columns:

**ServerName**

Name of the server.

**InstanceName**

Name of the server instance. Blank if the server is running as the default instance.

**IsClustered**

Indicates whether the server is part of a cluster.

**Version**

Version of the server (8.00.x for SQL Server 2000, and 9.00.x for SQL Server 2005).

Comment: Can I call this from Inno-setup (which uses some object-pascal like language ? )

Comment: sorry, i misread. I thought you were looking for a .Net solution.

Comment: You can use any kind of Win32 DLL.

Comment: @splash: Does that include managed .net dlls? If so then my original answer should work fine and bring back a list of all available SQL servers on the network.

Comment: Managed .net DLLs can only be used via a COM interface.